# Set plt.colorbar range with python/cartopy

Tags: python, range, maps, colorbar

Hello I have this code here, that I use to plot climate maps of aerosols.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np

from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

AODs_Season = netcdf_dataset('/home/vescovint/Documents/AOD_0219_DJF.nc')
lats = AODs_Season.variables['lat'][:]
lons = AODs_Season.variables['lon'][:]
AODS = AODs_Season.variables['AOD_550_Dark_Target_Deep_Blue_Combined_Mean_Mean'][0, :, :]

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())


plt.contourf(lons, lats, AODS, 60, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap='YlOrRd')
plt.colorbar(shrink=0.55)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15, 11)
ax.coastlines()

plt.savefig('/home/vescovint/Documents/AOD_Maps/DJF2002')
```

My problem is that, all my maps avec different range of value on the colorbar from 0 to 5 and i would to set it to min = 0 and max = 3.

I can't figure it out, if anyone can help me, I would be grateful.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can use clim() method from pyplot. For example:

```
plt.clim(0,3)
```

to set the color range of your plot (see [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clim.html))

Comment: My question wasn't really clear sorry. plt.clim() just change the color range of the colorbar, in my case i want to change the max value (the one given by the labels) so all my maps will be under 0 to 2 range of value.